# Odoo V12 JavaScript Framework

Tags: javascript, qweb, odoo-12

I have an issue with Odoo V12 Javascript Framework.
I don't know whather the javascript is loaded or there is another issue:

```
odoo.define('titi.Home',['web.core','web.Dialog','web.Class'], function(require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core'),
        Dialog = require('web.Dialog'),
        Class = require('web.Class');

    var TitiHouse = Dialog.extend({
        template: 'titi.her_house_name',
        events: {
            'click a#titi_s_house_name a': '_onClick',
        },
        init: function(parent, params) {
            var self = this;
            var options = _.extend({
                size: 'large',
                buttons: [{
                    text: params.titi_s_house_name,
                    click: self._onClick,
                    classes: 'btn-secondary',
                }],
            }, params || {});
            self._super(parent, options);
        },
        _onClick: function(event) {},
        willStart: function() {
            console.log('Will start .....');
        },
        start: function() {
            console.log('Start !!!');
        },
    });
    return TitiHouse;
});
```

When can I execute this javascript file in template?
Or how to execute that script in template?

Comment: <!-- My template file -->
<odoo>
   <template id="assets_backend or assets_frontend" inherit_id="website_sale.assets_backend or website_sale.assets_frontend">
      <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="toto/static/src/js/toto.house.js" />
      </xpath>
   </template>
</odoo>

Comment: if your console show 'start !!!', it means the file is well loaded

Comment: NOthing into my System Console and Chrome/Firefox console.

Comment: Into web.assets_frontend js file, i saw my script into but the navigator console return nada de chez nada or rien de chez rien !!!

Comment: If by template you mean the assets_backend, then your code is bundled with other Odoo js code into one big js file. I can't see any error in your code, but it will not show anything on the console unless you use the TitiHouse Dialgo. Also the Dialog class is a popup form (Bootstrap Modal), thus your console.log('...') statements will not be executed unless the dialog is used.

Comment: Try `Dialog.include()` instead of `Dialog.extend()`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that could be contributing to the problem:

1 - You are not calling the super methods of the Dialog widget in willStart or start. Try making these:

```js
...
willStart: function() {
    console.log('Will start .....');
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
},
start: function() {
    console.log('Start !!!');
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
},
...
```

2 - You are not extending the events, you are overridding them. You need to make your events param:

```js
events: _.extend({}, Dialog.prototype.events, {
    'click a#titi_s_house_name a': '_onClick',
}),
```

Try changing these and see if it helps.